# TableView row too high

Tags: uitableview, ios8, xcode6, tableview

I am using a TableViewController. I already unchecked `Adjust Scroll View Insets` as well as `Extended Edges` but it didn't help - the first cell is way too high. I am using Xcode 6.

[image: This is what it looks like in a simulator]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select style "Grouped" in Table View Attributes Inspector.
I see you asked more than half year ago but may be it will be useful for somebody else:)

Comment: Yeah, I don't need it, but maybe someone will, so accepting it :)

Comment: @RohitTigga: You have to select the `Table View`, Attribute Inspector and then it's the third item.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Tatsiana! Encountered the same problem when completing the chapter on UITableView, in the book *iOS Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide*. Great to finally have an answer! https://www.amazon.com/iOS-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides-ebook/dp/B00IG8TGZ8/ref=mt_kindle?_encoding=UTF8&me=